# How to rotate a rectangle continously in a specific angle in Java 3D

Tags: java, rotation, java-3d

I used the following code to rotate a rectangle along x-axis. But the problem is, I want to change the rotation angle continuously by loop, or by taking the values from user input. As I am new in java 3D, I have no idea how to do that. 
Any kind of help is great for me, THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
  SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();
  BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
  ColorCube c = new ColorCube(0.3);

  Transform3D t1 = new Transform3D();
  t1.rotX(Math.PI/2.0d);    

  TransformGroup tg1 = new TransformGroup(t1);

  tg1.addChild(c);
  group.addChild(tg1);
  group.compile();

  universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
  universe.addBranchGraph(group);
```

Comment: So create a while loop - change the the rotational angle by applying a function to the t1.rotX(Math.PI/2.0d) and make it redraw within each iteration of the loop.

If you want it to rotate constantly. I suggest you make a second thread to put your 'while(true)' loop within.

Comment: Actually I want to know the "redraw" process in detail in java 3D, because I used for loop but failed :( @Jay

Comment: Call tg1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE) and call tg1.setTransform() later somewhere with a new rotation to rotate it, look at this example (and ensure that you use Java3D 1.6.0): http://www.java3d.org/animationinteraction.html

Comment: @gouessej Mind to extend this to an answer? Otherwise, I could build one, just to avoid leaving this question "unanswered" (although, yes, it your be answered by a few websearches...)

Comment: if you have a suggestion, then please give it, because my problem hasn't been solved yet @Macro13

Comment: @Marco13 Done, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call TransformGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE) to allow your transform to be modified at runtime. Then, you must call TransformGroup.setTransform() later to modify its transform. It's up to you to pass it with a different transform to make it rotate, move, ... You can use the following example:
http://www.java3d.org/animationinteraction.html

You can use a timer to execute a task regularly. This task can modify the transform (by computing a new transform from the previous one) and you don't need to write a loop to do so.